# firebase Error : Missing or insufficient permissions with react js

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, react-redux-firebase

When using firebase
An error occurs as below.

> redux-firestore listener error: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

current firestore rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

If  change the firestore rule, it will work.

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: are you using firebase auth?

Comment: No.. Use only firesotre.

Comment: thats why it doesnt work

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first security rule requires that a user is signed in with Firebase Auth. If that's not the case, the error makes sense.

Your second rule opens up queries to anyone on the internet.  In fact, it allows all reads and writes, which is a fairly significant security problem.

I strongly suggest that you [learn how security rules work](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), and if security is a priority, to also use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) so you can determine who can read and write your database.